# Tensorflow CNN model get error " NaN loss during training."

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am a newer to tensorflow. 
When I training the data with cnn ,sometimes "NaN loss during training" is happened at the first batch.

```
> loss function is L1-norm
> 
> GradientDescentOptimizer is used.
```

"bach_size" ,"learning_rate" are adjust, even learning_rate = 0 is used.

What I really confused is when all parameters fixed, the result is sometimes can run normally ,sometimes get the error "Nan" at first batch. I want to know how it happens? what factors lead to the result?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The best way for volunteers here to diagnose your problem is trying to reproduce it. Try to improved this question by providing a small, self-contained and reproducible example - as it stands it is too much a guesswork.

Comment: Well, since we don't have your code it is hard to say for sure. But, most of the time there are a lot of random factors in training a neural net. Your training data is shuffled. Your initial weights are picked randomly from a distribution of some sort. Getting an occasional NaN in the loss function is not a big deal, but it might indicate that your loss function does not fit well with your data or network.

Comment: Thks @MadWombat~ you give the useful information about  the factors to that may lead to this issue commonly.

Answer (score 1):

- Check for NANs in your data
- RELU activation gives sometimes NANs